# Material design lite fix header but scrolling footer

Tags: css, material-design-lite

I am using Google's Material Design Lite to create my website but I have a problem with it. I wrote this code:

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--no-desktop-drawer-button">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header">

        <img class="mdl-layout-icon"></img>

        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
            ...
        </div>

    </header>
    <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
        ...
    </div>
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        ...
    </main>
    <footer class="mdl-mega-footer>
        ...
    </footer>
</div>
```

So, the problem is, that the footer is positioned to the bottom of the page, so both the header and the footer stick to the top and bottom of the window but I would like the footer to be scrollable, so I don't want to see it if the content is higher than the window, but I want the header to stay fixed to the top. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put the `<footer></footer>` within the `<main></main>` i.e

`<main>
<footer class="mdl-mega-footer"> ... </footer>
</main>`

Comment: putting it inside main causes some contents to overflow and there is a white space at the bottom below footer !!